# CXf- unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ns2.CustomerData"). Expected elements are <{customerbean}CustomerData>

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I am Using CXF for Developing a rest base web service.and in Get method application type is JSON. Using WADL I have generated code.

Issue 1 - In Data class `@XmlRootElement` is missing.

Now After adding it manually when I consume the service using generated client I got exception

```
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ns2.CustomerData"). Expected elements are <{customerbean}CustomerData>
```

I have gone through various post and if I remove namespace from my Data class as well as client data class then it works fine. But if namespace is removed than wadl2java doesn't work well.

I guess due to some thin server is not responding with proper namespace in response in case of JSON as the same will work if I change data type to XML

Comment: If you debug your code what are the values in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed namespace from `@XmlRootElement` and added the same into `@XmlType`, and it started working for me.